# Python3 importing module.py just a code part of main.py

Tags: python-3.x, import, pyqt5

This is a mdiWindow. `openChildWindow` action opens new child window. But I try to use import instead of class not working. I just want to short code lines instead of long code lines. I trying to use `child2.py` only part of `main.py` but not working. `import child2.py` doesn't make new mdiChildWindow.

main.py

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("mainWindow.ui",self)

        self.actionChildWindow.triggered.connect(self.openChild)        
        self.actionChildWindow2.triggered.connect(self.openChild2)

    def openChild(self): 
        childWindow=openChild("child.ui")
        childWindow.add(self.mdiArea)

    def openChild2(self): 
        import child2
        child2.childWindow2=openChild2("child2.ui")
        child2.childWindow2.add(self.mdiArea)

class openChild(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,modul):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(modul,self)

    def add(self,addToMainWindow):
        addToMainWindow.addSubWindow(self)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

child2.py

```
class openChild2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,modul):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(modul,self)

    def add(self,addToMainWindow):
        addToMainWindow.addSubWindow(self)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't really understand your question, could you try to explain it slightly more clearly?

Comment: actionChildWindow is working but actionChildWindow2 is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so theres a few issues with your code. I think they one you're talking about specifically is the issue with importing child2.py. Your problem is that you're trying to import inside of a function like this:

```
def openChild2(self): 
    import child2
    child2.childWindow2=openChild2("child2.ui")
    child2.childWindow2.add(self.mdiArea)
```

Really what you should be doing is importing at the start of the file like your other imports. Since you are only importing one class i like to use the from syntax for this. like so:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from child2 import openChild2
```

Then you can use openChild2 like the class was defined in your main.py file.